# one base executeQuery method or one for every query

Tags: java, database-connection, datamapper

I've started creating a toDoList and I like to create a "DataMapper" to fire queries to my Database.

I created this Datamapper to handle things for me but I don't know if my way of thinking is correct in this case. In my Datamapper I have created only 1 method that has to execute the queries and several methods that know what query to fire (to minimalize the open and close methods).

For example I have this:

```
public Object insertItem(String value) {

    this.value = value;

    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO toDoList(item,datum) " + "VALUES ('" + value + "', CURDATE())";

    return this.executeQuery(insertQuery);
}

public Object removeItem(int id) {

    this.itemId = id;
    String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id ='" + itemId + "'";

    return this.executeQuery(deleteQuery);

}

private ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {

    this.query = query;
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {

        con = db.connectToAndQueryDatabase(database, user, password);

        st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
    } 
    catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e2) { /* ignored */}
            }
            if (st != null) {
                try {
                    st.close();
                } catch (SQLException e2) { /* ignored */}
            }                       
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e2) { /* ignored */}
            }
            System.out.println("connection closed");
     }
    return rs;
}
```

So now I don't know if it's correct to return a `ResultSet` like this. I tought of doing something like

```
public ArrayList<ToDoListModel> getModel() {    
    return null;
}
```

To insert every record returned in a `ArrayList`. But I feel like I'm stuck a little bit. Can someone lead me to a right way with an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way the application works. If you have a lot of databases hits in a short time it would be better to bundle them and use the same database connection for all querys to reduce the overhead of the connection establishment and cleaning.

If you only have single querys in lager intervals you could do it this way.

You should also consider if you want to seperate the database layer and the user interface (if existing).
In this case you should not pass the `ResultSet` up to the user interface but wrap the data in an independent container and pass this through your application.

Comment: Can u give me an example of what u mean?

Comment: @Reshad To the bundeling: If you have like a lot of querys on different tables, which are automatically excecuted in a sequence it would be the best to open the connection, do all the tasks and then close it, not open and close a connection for each query. By the container I mean an object which is independent from the database, like an `Array`, `ArrayList` or may be a struct with two lists, one for the meta data and one for the actual data. That's what you would do if you using a multi tier architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly!, you need to pass a list of ToDoListModel objects
to insert into the DB using the **insertItem** method.

How you pass your object to insert items does not actually matter, but what you need to consider is how concurrent this DataMapper works, if it can be accessed by multiple threads at a time, you will end up creating multiple db connections which is little expensive.Your code actually works without any issue in sequential access.

So you can add a synchronized block to connection creation and make DataMapper class singleton.

Comment: No I need to get the item from the Database into a arrayList so I can view it in the application

Answer (score 0):

Ok in that case what you can do is, create a ArrayList of hashmap first. which contains Key, Value as Column name and Column value. After that you can create your model.

```
public List convertResultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
ResultSetMetaData mdata = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = mdata.getColumnCount();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
while (rs.next()){
    HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
    for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){           
   row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i));
}
   list.add(row);
}

return list;
}
```